# Как исправить ошибку ORA-00923, при попытке получить и использовать таблицы из БД?

Tags: sql, winforms, oracle, oledb

У меня есть четыре таблицы, к которым я обращаюсь, и загоняю их данные в DataGridView. Имена таблиц находятся в словаре, и имя выводимой таблицы определяется нажатием на кнопку с названием.

```
        private string currentTable;

    private Dictionary<string, int> numberOfColumns =
    new Dictionary<string, int> { {"Departments", 1 },
                                      {"Departments_Employees",  2 },
                                      {"Employees",       5 },
                                       {"Projects",    6 }
                                  };

    private void GetAndFillTable(string tableName)
    {
        int value = -1;
        if (numberOfColumns.TryGetValue(tableName, out value))
        {
            lastIndexTable = value;
            currentTable = tableName;
            LoadData();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Таблица {tableName} не найдена", "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    //пример смены таблицы

    private void ChTableToEmpls_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetAndFillTable("Employees");
    }


OleDbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select *, 'Delete' AS [Delete] FROM " + currentTable, OleDbConnection);

            OleDbCommandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(OleDbDataAdapter);

            OleDbCommandBuilder.GetInsertCommand();
            OleDbCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
            OleDbCommandBuilder.GetDeleteCommand();

            dataSet = new DataSet();

            OleDbDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, currentTable);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[currentTable];

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                DataGridViewLinkCell linkCell = new DataGridViewLinkCell();
                dataGridView1[lastIndexTable, i] = linkCell;
            }

            dataGridView1.Refresh();
            dataGridView1.Update();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

При запущенном приложении, при попытке вывести какую-либо таблицу по нажатию кнопки, выбрасывается исключение:

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Подобный код до этого использовался с MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что, SQL диалекты SQL Server и Oracle отличаются. Следует проверять работоспособность запросов в любом инструменте для отладки запросов.

В SQL Server [будет работать](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=62e68873d111e6a4fc7bfff00af1bf83):

```
Select *, 'Delete' AS [Delete] FROM tab
```

В Oracle этот же запрос [синтаксически неверен, и должен быть изменён](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=533716bb64cb9cb1dbb2046cb9e09e29):

```
Select tab.*, 'Delete' AS "Delete" FROM tab
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Буду знать.